# Интеграция Browsersync в rails приложении

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp, frontend

Как я могу использовать browsersync в приложении на rails?
Возможно ли обойтись более простыми методами чем вот этот?
https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-rails-pipeline
Обязательно ли использовать сборщики типа gulp или можно обойтись npm задачами?

Comment: А чем плох `gulp`?

Comment: Ничем. Возникают сложности с использованием его в rails приложении. Как мне настроить правильные пути к файлам и прочее? https://github.com/BrowserSync/recipes/blob/master/recipes/gulp.ruby.sass/gulpfile.js

Comment: В приложенном вами же шаблоне дан пример: вот [конфигурация с путями](https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-rails-pipeline/blob/master/gulp/config.js), вот [задача по сборке Sass](https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-rails-pipeline/blob/master/gulp/tasks/sass.js). Тут нет правильных вариантов, можно делать как вам удобно.

Comment: Прописал пути к файлам в конфиге. Собрал все задачи. Все работает кроме вот этого по ходу `.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));`. Потому что при изменении sass файлов выполняется задача сборки css, но в браузере изменения не применяются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### файл `config/environments/development.rb`

отключаем [метки](http://rusrails.ru/asset-pipeline#chto-za-metki-i-zachem-oni-nuzhny)

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

### файл `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

var setupWatchers = function() {
  gulp.watch(['./app/views/**/*.haml',
              './app/assets/javascripts/**/*'], ['reload']);
  gulp.watch(['./app/assets/stylesheets/**/*'], ['reloadCSS'])
};

gulp.task('reload', function(){
  return browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('reloadCSS', function() {
  return browserSync.reload('assets/application.css');
});

gulp.task('init', function() {
  browserSync.init({
      proxy: 'localhost:3000',
      port: 3001,
      open: true,
      ui: {
        port: 3002
      }
  });

  setupWatchers();
});

gulp.task('default', ['init']);
```